# How can I select “Allow” from System Preferences -> Security Panel to allow the installer to run from TERMINAL

Tags: macos, homebrew, system-settings, virtualbox

I am trying to install Docker on a macOS computer remotely from my Windows machine using a terminal connection. In order to to this, I run the following command on the Mac:

```
brew cask install virtualbox
```

However, I get an error.

From some websites, I learned that I should enable the "Allow" option from System Preferences > Security & Privacy, but I can't do this because I only have access to the terminal. How do I enable this option from the terminal?

Thank you.

Error message when I say "brew cask install virtualbox":

installer: Package name is Oracle VM VirtualBox installer: choices changes file '/var/folders/12/zxss37v145v2_xz8vvxt2lfm0000gn/T/choices20200708-6100-foe013.xml' applied installer: Installing at base path / installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)

The error message when I say "docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default":

Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed: (default) 0%... (default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter (default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory (default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface (default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp (default)

Comment: Could we see the error, please. Could you also tell us the version of macOS you are running. You might also add the output of `brew —version`.

Comment: @TonyWilliams I edited the question. My version is 10.13.6.